# Magento2.4.2 - How to get merged js and css URL?

Tags: magento2, javascript, css, magento2.4.2

I need to get the merged CSS and JS files URL for the current page. I have checked the core file `vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config/Renderer.php::renderHeadContent()`

```
public function renderHeadContent()
{
    ...........
    $result .= $this->renderAssets($this->getAvailableResultGroups());
    ...........
}
```

It seems like we need to pass the list of assets need to merge, then only it returns path. `vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/MergeService.php::getMergedAssets(array $assets, $contentType)`

```
/**
 * Return merged assets, if merging is enabled for a given content type
 *
 * @param MergeableInterface[] $assets
 * @param string $contentType
 * @return array|\Iterator
 * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
 */
public function getMergedAssets(array $assets, $contentType)
{
....................
....................
```

is there any other easy and proper way to get the merged CSS and js file URL?

Answer (score 0):

You can find your answer in this article: https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-enable-merge-css-javascript-magento-2.html

Comment: Thanks. I'm not asking about how to enable merge. I'm asking about get merged file URL? I found the solution I'll post it soon.